# Shaka player social share

Tags: html5-video, mpeg-dash

I'm using shaka player as my html5 DASH player, and i want to allow social network integrations.
For instance, share a clip to whatsapp/facebook or as a link for forums/websites.

Is it possible using Shaka player? (I can easily switch to working with DashJS if that is more flexible)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the link is pretty much independent from the player itself.

You will have the URL for the video stream already as this is what you will be giving to the player, so you really just need to use the standard social network API's to share this link.

Some players will have this functionality included as an overlay or control on the video, which may be what you mean - however, you can still share the link your self by just adding your own share button below it on your web page.

I'm not aware of any Shaka Plugin to allow it be included in the controls, but if you wanted to add it yourself all the controls are grouped in:

- https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/7169c7a5902696a42419b67a9c8e091e7f06c95d/demo/common/controls.js

For example you can see how the mute button is handled when it is clicked here:

```js
/** @private */
ShakaControls.prototype.onMuteClick_ = function() {
  if (!this.enabled_) return;

  this.video_.muted = !this.video_.muted;
};
```

You could add a control to call the required social network sharing API for your case.